# Issue with using Microsoft Graph Async method to populate view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC controller that calls Microsoft Graph API to obtain AD group information, which then are used to populate a view like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }   
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ADInquiry(string groupName)
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();    
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName))
        {
            return View(vm);
        }

        var groupInfo = await _graphServiceClient.Groups.Request()
             .Filter($"displayName eq '{groupName}'")
             .Select("id")
             .GetAsync();

        // Transform groupInfo to populate view model
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<form asp-action="ADInquiry" method="post">
    <div class="mb-3 mt-3 row">
        <label for="@Model.GroupName" class="col-2 col-form-label text-end">Username or Group name</label>
        <div class="col-1">
            <input asp-for="@Model.GroupName" type="text" class="form-control col-2" placeholder="Group Name">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fas fa-search" title="Search"> Search</i>
        </button>

    </div>
</form>
<table>
     @* Show data in table *@
```

Here is the middleware that injects GraphServiceClient

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

The issue is with the async call

```
var groupInfo = await _graphServiceClient.Groups.Request()
```

When I enter the group name in the textbox, and click the "search" button, at the first round when this async call is reached, the tread is released back to UI while the service reaches https://login.microsoftonline.com to grab access token.

I expect the process then to continue on to line below,

```
// Transform groupInfo to populate view model....
```

Instead, it returns to the first line of the method with NULL input parameter groupName, and enter the

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName)) {}
```

I repeat the same process again(entering group name in textbox, click the search button). This time, the process continues on to populate the view model and present  proper info on the view.

I think this has something to do with the async process, and the success of the second try is due to the access token still valid. What I don't know is how to fix it.

Comment: What calls `ADInquiry`?  I'd post that call stack.  Using await definitely does not cause the method to re-run.  I suspect you aren't using await up the entire call chain.  Post all applicable code that can repro the problem.

Comment: Hi, ADInquiry is called from the form post
`<form asp-action="ADInquiry" method="post">`
_graphServiceClient is injected from middleware. I've edited the original post and added the missing code.